# Moodle Reading data from Database: How to SELECT the first record which meets the WHERE clause? TOP does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

I want to retrieve the blog post *title of the **latest** blog post by* a particular user with the `id` stored in `$myUserId`. So [from this doc](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API), I have learnt to do this:

```
$latestPostSubject = $DB->get_record_sql('SELECT subject FROM {post} WHERE userid = ?', array($meUserId));
```

**The problem is that this returns all the blog posts by the user, while I need *only the latest one*.**

---

***WHAT I TRIED:***

1. So when I try something like

   ```
   $latestPostSubject = $DB->get_record_sql('SELECT TOP(1) subject FROM {post} WHERE userid = ?', array($meUserId));
   ```

   [Reference.](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_top.php)

   I get a syntax error.

> Error Reading from Database.
>
> Debug info: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM mdl_post WHERE userid = '2'' at line 1 SELECT TOP(1) *
>   FROM mdl_post WHERE userid = ? [array ( 0 => '2', )]
>
> Error code: dmlreadexception

2. The [`post` table](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=195214) also contains a `created` and `lastmodified`
   fields, but when I printed the entire record of the user with the `*`
   from the `post` table, I failed to understand the format of the date

   - it's a 10 digit number :s ***Otherwise I would do some math on the dates on which the blog posts were created.***

     ...[lastmodified] => 1432051856 [created] => 1432051855...

---

***QUESTION:***

**So what should I do to get the latest blog post from the table?**

**Secondly, why doesn't the `TOP(1)` in the SQL statement work?**

Comment: 2nd: `TOP` is a clause not function. So it should be like this `TOP 1`. Now it might work.

Comment: @Beginner Nah. I had tried that as well. I resulted in the same error.

Comment: In the error the query is *SELECT TOP(1) \* FROM mdl_post WHERE userid = ?*. You don't need `*`.

Comment: Regarding the ten digit number, it's in milliseconds. See: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time and http://www.epochconverter.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.subject
        FROM {post} p
        WHERE p.userid = :userid
        ORDER BY p.id DESC";
$params = array('userid' => $my_user_id);
$latest_post_subject = $DB->get_record_sql($sql, $params, IGNORE_MULTIPLE);
```

Pin this page as a reference - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

Moodle can use several different databases so the SQL should generic

Actually if you just want the title you can use get_field

```
$sql = "SELECT p.subject
        FROM {post} p
        WHERE p.userid = :userid
        ORDER BY p.id DESC";
$params = array('userid' => $my_user_id);
$latest_post_subject = $DB->get_field_sql($sql, $params, IGNORE_MULTIPLE);
```

For displaying the date use the user_date($time) function. The time is stored in GMT and in unix time. The user_date() function will display the date in the current users timezone and date/time format.